# Login with Jquery Colorbox Plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, same-origin-policy

I used Jquery Colorbox lightbox plugin in order to let users to login to my site ,this plugin use signin.aspx page (which i made) in order to evaluate the user's credentials, but the problem is when someone try to signin ,I'm facing this error:
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.example.com".
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http",
the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
Any Idea(s)? I would really appreciate

Comment: Provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page the frame is on and the page you are loading into the lightbox (signin.aspx) must both be on the same domain (including protocol). This is called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you want the popup to always be the same protocol, use a protocol-less url:

```
//example.com/signin.aspx
```

This will then use the protocol of the parent document (http or https)

Comment: They are in same domain ,but the protocol should be same as well ,I mean both should be under "https://" or "http://" ? or the reason might be something else ?

Comment: Yes, both should be on the same protocol

Comment: Thanks for response,but the Problem is I provide my pop up window in menu bar of my master page ,so that in every page user can click the login link and pop up window appears for them ,but some pages are under http:// protocol and some are under https// how can provide solution for this scenario ?

Comment: I've added some detail to my answer about using a protocol-less domain